# Set Semantic-UI dropdown selected using array or string

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

The snippet is what i got, by setting set selected 1 by 1 manually it work.
But i want to do it programmatically like passing a string or an array that contain `["2", "3", "4"]` to the `set selected: array` or any other way i can insert an array i receive from ajax.

```js
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown('set selected', ["1", "2"]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.0/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.0/semantic.min.js"></script>
<select multiple class="ui dropdown" name="event">
    <option value="">Select Service</option>
    <option value="1">opt 1</option>
    <option value="2">opt 2</option>
    <option value="3">opt 3</option>
    <option value="4">opt 4</option>
    <option value="5">opt 5</option>
</select>
```

I also tried using Remote Content as below, but the `selected` doesn't seem to work.

json output:

```
"success": true,
"results": [
  {
    "name"  : "Choice 1",
    "value" : "value1",
    "selected" : true
   }
```

Read the Remote content:

```
 $('.ui.dropdown.state').dropdown({
  apiSettings: {
     url: '//api.semantic-ui.com/tags/{query}'
  },
   filterRemoteData: false
}); `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. My mistake was i call the array outside of ajax onload method. By calling the `set selected` inside a loop in within `onload` call, solved it.
selectedArray should contain the value of the targeted option.

```
for(var i=0, len=selectedArray.length; i <len; i++){
   $('.ui.dropdown.state').dropdown('set selected', selectedArray[i]);
}
```